# jquery: iterate through tables comparing <td>hardcoded date</td> against Date.today() then dropping dates<today

Tags: jquery, datejs

Thanks to all for considering my newbe issue. 
I'm using jQuery to iterate through a table and capture all hardcoded dates in an array. 
I compare those dates against Date.today(); using .isAfter() function. 
If hardcoded date is in the past, it should get a .css("display", "none");

```
<table>
    <html>
      <table>
        <tr class="gig">

           <td class="gigDate">Mar 27 2013</td>
           <td>the Saloon</td>
           <td>Atlanta, Ga</td>
           <td>$20 (2 passes)</td>
            <td>button to purchase tix<td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="gig"><td class="gigDate"> ... date2 ..</td></tr>
        <tr class="gig"><td class="gigDate"> ... date3 ..</td></tr>
        <tr class="gig"><td class="gigDate"> ... date4 ect ..</td></tr>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready( function() {

var stringDate = []; //create array to hold elements

var now = Date.today(); // create current date

$('.gigDate').each(function (i, e) {   //adds hardcoded dates to array
stringDate.push($(e).text());
});

for(var y = 0; y < stringDate.length; y++){
var singleDate =  Date.parse(stringDate[y]);  //parse to milliseconds
var compare = now.isAfter(singleDate);        //compare to today's date

if(compare){
    $('.gig').css("display", "none");   //hide <tr class="gig"> 
                                      //if in the past
      }
}    
 });
</script>
```

Loop logic seems to function properly, but the if(statement) that adds style display:none is  whack. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to hide a single row, you just hide all of them -  $('.gig') selects all rows, not just the one you think it should.

Move your logic inside the loop where you test the date. Roughly like this (I'm changing your code as little as possible, might still not work, haven't checked):

```
var now = Date.today(); // create current date

$('.gigDate').each(function (i, e) {   //adds hardcoded dates to array
   var current = ($(e).text());
   var singleDate =  Date.parse(current);  //parse to milliseconds
   var compare = now.isAfter(singleDate);        //compare to today's date
   if(compare){
       // we want to hide the parent of td, not the td:
       $(e).parent().css("display", "none");   //hide <tr class="gig"> 
                                      //if in the past
   }

});
```

Comment: Forgot to comment, @fdreger many thanks, the .parent().css() did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this isAfter function, but you can compare dates directly. I guess that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're filtering client-side? Seems inefficient.  Is your html hard coded or do you have server-side scripting at all?  You really should filter your results pre-render, unless there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the compare worked you'd be hiding anything with class 'gig'.

You can simplify this by creating a new Date(xxxxxxx) from your strings. Then you can just compare using a '<' operator.

Assuming your gig dates are the same format as your event dates:

```
var now = new Date(); // create current date    
$('.gigDate').each(function (i, e) { 
    ele = $(this).html();
    gigDate = new Date(ele);
    if (gigDate<now){
        $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/vzH8U/